# Dojo accessing a javascript object in external file

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am trying to access a simple javascript variable / object I defined in an external file. My question is how to load it by dojo. Here is my [plunker code](https://plnkr.co/edit/O8DcXIYAKrrBPgYdgOx6?p=preview) that didn't work:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Tutorial: Hello Dojo!</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- load Dojo -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"
            data-dojo-config="async: true"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        require({
        packages: [
        {
                name: 'myApp',
                location: window.location.href.replace(/\/$/, "")
        }]}, 
        ["dojo/dom", "myApp/config", "dojo/domReady!"], function(dom, config) {
          console.log(config.keys);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

config.js

```
var keys = {
    "key_1": {
        "your_name": "jimmy",
        "your_msg": "hello world"
    },
    "key_2": {
        "your_name": "billy",
        "your_msg": "foo equals bar"
    }
};
```

As you can see I tried to load the config.js file as config, and tried to access it as config in my code. I am getting undefined in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some research and what I need to use looks like the dojo's define function so that config.js looks like this:

```
define({
  keys : {
    "key_1": {
        "your_name": "jimmy",
        "your_msg": "hello world"
    },
    "key_2": {
        "your_name": "billy",
        "your_msg": "foo equals bar"
    }
}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define a module for your configuration file.
This can be achieved using the `define` passing as argument your object.

Basic example:

```
define({ yourProperty: yourValue});
```

More information can be found here: https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/modules/